# Creating namespace for XML element

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-8

I have problem with adding new node (with namespace) to my xml document which is used to generating xaml. I'm doing it like this:

```
XmlElement richTextColumns = xmlDoc.CreateElement("local2:RichTextColumns");
```

but i receive error 0xC00CE01D (while calling xmlDoc.getxml). I have tried adding attribute xmlns:local2="using:App2.Common" to xmlDoc:

```
var att = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:local2");
att.InnerText = "using:Dictionary.Common";
xmlDoc.Attributes.SetNamedItem(att);
```

it results in this error

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to create an element with a specific namespace use [this call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument.createelementns):

```
xmlDoc.CreateElementNS("using:Dictionary.Common", "local2:elementName")
```

Comment: In win8 there is no  xmlDoc.CreateElement that takes 3 args :/

Comment: What XML API are you using?  I assumed you were using `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

Comment: "there is no System.Xml.XmlDocument in system.xml" :/

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API, but it looks like you can use the CreateElementNS method, supplying "using:Dictionary.Common" and "local2:elementName" as parameters.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335908(v=vs.71)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335908%28v=vs.71%29), the CreateAttribute method with a single parameter does not set the namespace, but the name of the element. Try to use one of the other permutations of this method.

Comment: there is only function createElement with one arg in windows8

Answer (score 1):

You can create an element as you would typically do and then load the document back and add the namespace atribute you are looking to add.

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("link to yuor xml");
    XNamespace xmlns = "local2";
    public static void SetDefaultXmlNamespace(XElement xelem, XNamespace xmlns)
    {

        foreach(var e in xelem.Elements())
            e.SetDefaultXmlNamespace(xmlns);
    }

    doc.Root.SetDefaultXmlNamespace("local2")
```

Comment: Could you write something more? I don't know how to access doc.Root element.